# Вычисление определителя при помощи правила Саррюса

Tags: c, матрицы

Ув. пользователи, помогите пожалуйста разобраться в вычислении определителя матрицы [методом Саррюса](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%80%D1%8E%D1%81%D0%B0), а точнее подкорректировать алгоритм, во втором цикле

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
srand(time(NULL));

const int col = 5, row = 3;

int matrix[col][row] = {};
int det = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < row; cout << endl, i++)  // инициализация матрицы случайными значениями
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        if (j < 3) cout << (matrix[i][j] = rand() % 5 + 1) << " ";
        else matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j - 3];
    }

for (int i = 0; i == 0 && i < row; cout << endl, i++) // вычисление определителя
    for (int j = 0; j < col + 1; j++)
        (j < 3) ? det += (matrix[i][j] * matrix[i + 1][j + 1] * matrix[i + 2][j + 2]) : det -= (matrix[i][j - 1] * matrix[i + 1][j - 2] * matrix[i + 2][j - 3]);

cout << "det = " << det << endl;
}
```

Собственно, выражение `det -= (matrix[i][j - 1] * matrix[i + 1][j - 2] * matrix[i + 2][j - 3])` работает неправильно в последних двух итерациях. Почему? Как исправить?

Comment: Благодаря этому условию   i == 0 && i < row; цикл выполнится только один раз. А благодаря этому условию j < col + 1 программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow условие `i == 0 && i < row;` задано так, потому что выражение решается за одну итерацию цикла `i`, т. е. если значение `i` будет больше, то будет выход за пределы матрицы по строкам (см. формулу)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow условие  `j < col + 1` можно поменять на `j <= col` в данном случае оно не играет особой роли

Comment: если i  фиксирована, то не имеет смысл писать цикл. Что касается внутреннего цикла, то происходит обращение к памяти за пределами массива при j равным col

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow пусть так, но тогда почему в предпоследней итерации вложенного цикла, когда  значение  `j` еще не равно `col` значение уже не соответствует правилу Саррюса?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow имеется ввиду значение переменной `del`

Comment: Уж для Сарюса использовать циклы - никакого смысла...

Comment: @Harry согласен, давно бы сделал без них, но мне велели иначе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаете, вот это:

```
det = matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][2]+matrix[1][0]*matrix[0][2]*matrix[2][1]+
      matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][0]-matrix[2][0]*matrix[1][1]*matrix[0][2]-
      matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][2]-matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][1];
```

вряд ли длиннее, и уж точно с меньшими накладными расходами, чем ваше

```
for (int i = 0; i == 0 && i < row; cout << endl, i++) // вычисление определителя
    for (int j = 0; j < col + 1; j++)
        (j < 3) ? det += (matrix[i][j] * matrix[i + 1][j + 1] * matrix[i + 2][j + 2])
                : det -= (matrix[i][j - 1] * matrix[i + 1][j - 2] * matrix[i + 2][j - 3]);
```

Для таких простых формул не имеет смысла придумывать сложные решения...

**Update**

Через цикл - так через цикл...

```
double matrix[3][3];


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    srand(time(0));

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            matrix[i][j] = rand()%20 - 10;


    double det = matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]*matrix[2][2]+matrix[1][0]*matrix[0][2]*matrix[2][1]+
        matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][0]-matrix[2][0]*matrix[1][1]*matrix[0][2]-
        matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]*matrix[2][2]-matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][2]*matrix[2][1];


    double d2 = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            if (j == i) continue;
            int k = 3-i-j;
            double x = matrix[0][i]*matrix[1][j]*matrix[2][k];
            x *= ((i-j)*(j-k)*(k-i) > 0) ? 1 : -1;
            d2 += x;
        }
    }

    printf("%lf\n",det);
    printf("%lf\n",d2);

}
```

Как видите, результат правильный :)

Comment: понимаю, так намного проще и быстрей, я бы тоже так сделал, но мой сэнсэй настоял, чтобы задание было решено при помощи цикла, поэтому, видимо, придется самому додумывать

Comment: Ну смотрите исправленный ответ - с циклами :)

Comment: Я бы вместо третьего цикла написал `k=3-i-j`.

Comment: @Mikhailo Спасибо, вы совершенно правы. *"Как я сам не дотумкал"* (с)